How to Migrate existing springboot api gateway service to KrackenD
Im trying to migrate an existing api gateway microservice which was build using java springboot to KrackenD as zuul is deprecated. But im not able to find any tutorials or a step by step guide on how to do it.Im not understanding on where do I start or how. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks
I was try’n to upgrade springboot from 1.x to 2.7 . However, I got to know that zuul is deprecated. Hence, Im unable to proceed with anything. I got a suggestion to use KrackenD but i have no idea where or how to start migrating it
